# PhoneGap dial function on android Tablet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I make an app...But I found a problem.
I Use telephony hardware for make a call for smartphone..
in my source i use

```
ng-click="openDial(tel)">
```

I need to detect SMARTPHONE or TABLET for show or hide DIAL DIV
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make some guesses based on userAgent, perhaps on phoneGap's device info API, maybe some other things. It may be possible that there is some native API for figuring out if a dialer app is available .. but considering that it's entirely possible that a tablet could have something registered to dial numbers (at least in Android .. such as Skype or other VOIP dialers), perhaps you should just let it be.